# Custom function failing to convert a decimal to single precision floating point

Tags: algorithm, matlab, octave, ieee-754

Here is a code attempting to convert a real number to its approximate single precision floating point representation, for educational purposes to demonstrate the intermediate results:

```
function [IEEE] = myDec2IEEE (d)
% Accepts a decimal number, d.
% Returns 1x32 bit array holding its closest IEEE representation. 

  s = getSign(d);                    

  [e, f] = getCharacteristic(d);

  binaryE = binStr2binArr(dec2bin(e));  % convert to binary integer array.

  if numel(binaryE) < 8                 % extend to exponent bits number.
    binaryE = [zeros(1, 8 - numel(binaryE)), binaryE];
  end

  binaryF = expandFractionToBinary(f);

  IEEE = [s , binaryE, binaryF]; 
end

function [B] = binStr2binArr (s)
% Accepts a binary character string, s.
% Returns binary integer array, B.

  len = numel(s);
  B = zeros(1, len);

  for i = 1 : len
    B(i) = s(i) - '0';  
  end  

end  

function [B] = expandFractionToBinary(f)
% Accepts what has remained from the decimal number 
% after the calculation of the exponent, i.e its fractional part.  
% Returns a 1x23 binary array which is the approximation of the 
% fractional part represented as a sum of negative powers of 2,
% (up to the 22 - nd power).

  singlePrecision = 22;
  B = zeros(1, singlePrecision); % binary string to store fraction of IEEE754.
  i = 1;                         % exponent of 2; (i+1) -index in binary array. 

  while f != 0 && i <= singlePrecision

    ith = 1 / (2^(i));

    if ith <= f
  
      f = f - ith; 
      B(i) = 1;                  % include coefficient in the sum.
  
    end  

    i = i + 1;
  end

end  

function [e, f] = getCharacteristic (d)
% Accepts a number is base10, d.
% Returns the exponent and fraction in d's IEEE754 representation, in base10.

% write d in base-2 scientific  notation 
% i.e. factor it into number in the range [1, 2] and a power of 2.
  bias = 127;
  i = 1;
  f = 0;

  while ~(f >= 1 && f <= 2) 

    f = d / (2^(-i));
    % pause; % if number > 1 the denominator -> 0 and (faster than f -> Inf)
    i = i + 1;   
  end  

  i = i - 1;  % last check is done after incrementation.

  e = bias - i;
  f = f - 1;
end  

function [s] = getSign (d)
% Accepts a number in base10, d.
% Returns the sign bit of its IEEE754 representation.

  if d >= 0 
    s = 0;  
  else  
    s = 1;
  end  
end
```

Input:

```
IEEE = myDec2IEEE(0.085)
```

Output:

```
Columns 1 through 21:

0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0

Columns 22 through 31:

1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
```

However, it works only for decimal numbers in: 0 < d < 1.

### Questions

What am I doing wrong?

How should the code by modified to correctly return IEEE representations of numbers >= 1 and d <= 0?

---

#### Note:

Implementation based on the relation d = (-1)<sup>sign</sup> * 2<sup>exponent - bias</sup> * (fraction + 1), where fraction = Sum (1/2^n), n = 0,...,22; bias = 127.

Comment: You have a function to expand the fractional portion to binary, now you need the equivalent operation to expand the integer portion to binary.

Comment: @beaker do I add it to the exponent, the integer part that is?

Comment: No, the integer part is a part of the significand just like the fractional part is. The exponent is the same as that of the most significant 1 bit in the number (plus the bias, of course).

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) MATLAB uses IEEE 754 for single precision floats.

As such why not let MATLAB handle the internals and do something like this?:

```
s = dec2bin(typecast(single(0.085),'uint32'), 32)
```

Which gives:

```
00111101101011100001010001111011
```

This matches the required output (from the [independent check](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) you mention) and also works for values > 1.

If you need a numeric, rather than string, result you could convert it like this:

```
x = s-'0'
```